# DSUM Existing Field in Access Query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to reference a field in my query in a DSUM Expression in the same query but I can't get it to work. Could you please help?

I want my 'Total $ Accrual' column in the below query to sum the 'Amount $' amounts in the 'Accruals Raw Data' table for each Accrual ID from the 'Accruals Master Data' table (as they are displayed in the query when the query runs).

[image]

When I run it the query opens an input box window instead.

[image]

I originally tried using the below formula but it says the field may refer to the 'Accrual ID' in more than 1 table, therefore I have tried to reference the field within the query using the screenshot instead.

*Total $ Accrual: DSum("[Amount $]","Accruals Raw Data","[Accrual ID]='" & [Accrual ID] & "'")*

Many Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS Access? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Total $ Accrual: DSum("[Amount $]","[Accruals Raw Data]","[Accrual ID]='" & [Accruals Master Data].[Accrual ID] & "'")
```

You have 2 tables in query with the same column name [Accrual ID], so Access asked to clarify which table you are referencing to.

Comment: Hi Sergey, The above isn't returning results. Also, the addition of [Accruals Raw Data] above at the end of the expression refers to the Raw Data table. Can I get the DSUM to refer to the 'Accrual ID' field in the query iteself? Thanks

Comment: Just noticed that you have outer join, edited the answer. It should refer to Master table. And yes, you can calculate sum in the query without DSum, just add totals and select `Sum` function for [Amount $] field. This query will work faster, but variant with DSum can be used in update queries, second one - not.